# How to left shift column value in spark sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have the following table

| Team | Team_Category | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 | Score5 | Score6 | Score7 | Score8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A41 | Bikes | 40 |  |  | 91 |  |  | 51 |  |
| A57 | Bicycles |  |  |  |  | 60 |  |  | 47 |

I want to left shift the values if a previous score is `NULL` or `""` 
The required output is:

| Team | Team_Category | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 | Score5 | Score6 | Score7 | Score8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A41 | Bikes | 40 | 91 | 51 |  |  |  |  |  |
| A57 | Bicycles | 60 | 47 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I tried using `coalesce` like

`spark.sql("""SELECT Team, Team_Category, COALESCE(NULLIF(Score1,""),NULLIF(Score2,""),...NULLIF(Score8,"")) AS Score1, COALESCE(NULLIF(Score2,""),NULLIF(Score3,"")...NULLIF(Score8,"")) AS Score2,...""")`

but this would only solve half the problem. Even though the values will now be moved to the left, the values on the right will still be there.

How can this be done using spark sql?

Note: A team can have multiple rows, but they are independent from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array from the `Score` columns then use `array_compact` to remove nulls finally based on the new position of each element in the array reassign the scores columns back to the dataframe

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Score')]

arr = F.array_compact(F.array(*cols))
df1 = df.select('Team', 'Team_Category', *[arr[i].alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)])
```

---

```
+----+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|Team|Team_Category|Score1|Score2|Score3|Score4|Score5|Score6|Score7|Score8|
+----+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A41|        Bikes|    40|    91|    51|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| A57|     Bicycles|    60|    47|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
+----+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Note: `array_compact` is only available starting from spark 3.4.0 if you are using an old version then we can use `filter` insstead: `arr = F.filter(F.array(*cols), lambda x: x.isNotNull())`